# AT Commands ESP8266 Arduino IDE serial monitor not print any data from server. It say 408 request timeout

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno

i am new in arduino and ESP8266 module. I am still learning about AT command. But i found this problem:

1.My website code (index.html)-http://nyalalampu.atwebpages.com:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
        ECHO $_GET['subject'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

2.My AT commands (In Arduino IDE Serial Monitor)

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","nyalalampu.atwebpages.com",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=29


OK
> 
Recv 29 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,391:HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Date: Sat, 10 Oct 2020 17:00:24 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 221
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>408 Request Timeout</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Timeout</h1>
<p>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</p>
</body></html>
CLOSED
```

After > i put

```
GET /?subject=anis HTTP/1.0
```

My question is why it not print **anis** in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor? It just show 408 Request Timeout

I hope someone can tell me what's wrong with my code.TQ

Comment: you must end the GET request with \r\n. how do you send it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESP8266 ESP-01 not show data from server in Arduino IDE serial monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64290187/esp8266-esp-01-not-show-data-from-server-in-arduino-ide-serial-monitor)

Comment: I just send like you say sir...but it send back Bad Request when i put \r\n like this GET /?subject=anis HTTP/1.0 \r\n

Comment: @Juraj I just send like you say sir...but it send back Bad Request when i put \r\n like this GET /?subject=anis HTTP/1.0 \r\n

Comment: @Juraj Yes...i have learn something new...tq sir...what i know is AT+CIPSEND value should same the count of character plus 2

Comment: `/?subject=anis HTTP/1.0 \r\n` the space before \r\n shouldn't be there

Comment: @Juraj still get Bad Request after i remove space

Comment: you have the GET line in the sketch or you try to send it from Serial Monitor?

Comment: @Juraj in Serial Monitor sir

Comment: then remove \r\n and after sending the GET line, try to press Enter immediately one more time. does the server accept insecure http? does it accept HTTP 1.0?

Comment: you need "host" header